# Derivative of a vector function for velocity in terms of position

Tags: vector-fields

I am working with a 2D vector field for velocity in the $xy$-coordinate plane.  Given

$$v(x,y) = i_x * x - i_y * y$$

where $v$ denotes velocity and $i_x$ and $i_y$ are the unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively, how do I find the acceleration $a(x,y)$?  I know that the traditional vector function has its' $x$ and $y$ components as functions of time $t$, but the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not available.

Comment: How would you define acceleration without reference to time?

Comment: That's the point, x and y are functions of t, but I don't know what they are.  It seems like a differential equation, except with a vector field.  It's really weird and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: My question is what does “acceleration” even mean in this context?